# How to create an object in an object in a document in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I want to have a document like this in my details collection,

```
{
id:1,
name:'Jake',
address:{
   city:'salem',
   country:'Jordan'
}
}
```

So far, I have tried this command in mongo shell,

```
db.details.insert({id:1,name:'Jake',address:{city:'Salem',country:'Jordan'}});
```

But I have this error message,

```
SyntaxError: invalid property id.
```

Why do i have this error message and how do i perform the insert operation for this document?

Comment: The query is perfectly fine. Did you copy correctly??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try ?

```
db.details.insert({_id:1,name:'Jake',address:{city:'Salem',country:'Jordan'}});
```

In mongodb the `id` field is usually named `_id`.

I guess that your collection as a json schema validation that block the `id` field.

Comment: Actually I tried something like this,    db.details.insert({id:1,name:'Jake',address:{city-name:'salem',country-name:'Jordan'}}). If I remove the hyphen, it works. Why does this happen?

Comment: city-name is not json compliant. You should use this syntax : "city-name"

Answer (score 0):

try this shape and tell me if it work or not 
or repqce id by _id it genarated -autamatic by mongodb

```
db.details.insert({_id:1,name:'Jake',address:{   city:'salem',   country:'Jordan'}});
```

)